# Не получается импортировать модуль в admin.py в Django

Tags: python, django

Привет!
Начал изучать django и столкнулся с проблемой которую самому решить никак не удалось.Выскакивает следующая ошибка.сейчас python и django стоят глобально.та же самая ошибка сыпалась и в проекте через virtualenv и pyvenv на win 10.причём в Ubuntu такой ошибки не было хотя делал тоже самое.Пишет вроде как нет модуля хотя в pycharm автокомплит ищет этот модуль, работает,ничего не подсвечивает и всё вставляется без ошибок.запускаю сервер и:

```
F:\web\ghc>manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x03AB9300>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
self.module.autodiscover()
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
File "C:\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "F:\web\ghc\news\admin.py", line 3, in <module>
from ghc.news.models import News
ImportError: No module named 'ghc.news'


Код models.py:
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):
title = models.TextField(u'Заголовок')


Код admin.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from ghc.news.models import News

admin.site.register(News)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: версий может несколько установлено, не?

Comment: А если `from news.models import News` сделать?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev да так получилось.странно что в книге и на некоторых ресурсах указывается имя пакета.видимо мной использовался какой то устаревший метод импорта...Спасибо!!!теперь всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в способе импорта в новых версиях django структура проекта изменена. Импорт идет от положения файла manage.py

Ошибка from ghc.news.models import News

Верно:

```
from news.models import News
```

Но учитывая что работаете на 3 питоне который поддерживает относительный импорт и вызов идет из того же пакета

Лучше (python 3)

```
from .models import News
```

Не нужно думать как назвал приложение, при копипасте часто спасает от ошибок импорта из другого приложения.